# Session map is null when printed

Tags: session, jsf

I am working on JSF1.1 with JSP as presentation technology.
I have a managed bean with an ArrayList and I display the list in  as rows. 
Everything works fine. I have session replication with two server nodes and when I replicate the session, and put one of the cluster down, app is now on second cluster but the session attributes are lost.

I tried to print sessionMap using ExternalContext to see session attributes but that is null too.

What could be a possible reason?

Comment: mali if possible then please send me code that how do you set and get ExternalContext  and sessionMap, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes are likely not [`Serializable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). That's a requirement to get them to persist on disk and/or to transfer as bytes over network.

To fix this, just ensure that all session attributes (including session scoped managed beans) implement `Serializable` like this:

```
public class SomeSessionClass implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

Don't forget to make any members `Serializable` as well whenever applicable. E.g.

```
public class SomeSessionClass implements Serializable {
    private SomeNestedClass foo; // Has to implement Serializable as well!
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I created a class implements serializable and declare a variable int which I just want to see as a counter. Same case as above, whenever I switch node I lost my attribute value. Please help me in this.